# Could not access the model deployed on lab server using Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to follow the [tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-easily-deploy-machine-learning-models-using-flask-b95af8fe34d4) to deploy a machine learning model on my lab's server so every one in my lab could give it a try. This tutorial is deploying a Logistic regression model to predict the sales, but I believe it should also work in my case.

The following is the complete code:

- `app.py` on my lab server, where `model.pkl` is a pickled Logistic regression model and `index.html` is some GUI code.

```py
import numpy as np
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
import pickle

app = Flask(__name__)
model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl', 'rb'))

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/predict',methods=['POST'])
def predict():

    int_features = [int(x) for x in request.form.values()]
    final_features = [np.array(int_features)]
    prediction = model.predict(final_features)

    output = round(prediction[0], 2)

    return render_template('index.html', prediction_text='Sales should be $ {}'.format(output))

@app.route('/results',methods=['POST'])
def results():

    data = request.get_json(force=True)
    prediction = model.predict([np.array(list(data.values()))])

    output = prediction[0]
    return jsonify(output)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=False, host='0.0.0.0')
```

- `request.py` on my local machine

```py
import requests

data = {'rate':5, 'sales_in_first_month':200, 'sales_in_second_month':400}

url = "http://<ip-address>/results"
r = requests.post(
    url,
    json=data
)

print(r.json())
```

But when I `python app.py` to let the application running **on the lab server** (the real IP address is replaced with `<ip-address>`) and then `python request.py` **on my local machine**, it seems that I still could not access the server as there are no responses.

```bash
 * Serving Flask app 'app'
 * Debug mode: off
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://<ip-address>:5000
```

I do need a username and a password to log into my lab's server. But I am not sure login credential is required here.
To my understanding, anyone with the IP address could interact with the model.

Did I do something wrong here? Any input is appreciated!

Comment: what's the response that you get? try it as a curl request to check the response code. also, `Running on http://<ip-address>:5000` seems like you are running it on port 5000, but in `request.py` you are just hitting `http://<ip-address>/results`..

Comment: Please make sure to specify `host='0.0.0.0'` while starting your app, i.e., `app.run(host='0.0.0.0')`. Additionally, the port `5000` might be blocked on the (VM) lab's machine for Python; in that case, you would need to create an inbound firewall rule for Python and allow traffic on this port. If you are accessing the lab's machine through a different network, you would need to set up [port forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) on your lab's router, which might not be feasible, and hence, you may want to search for other options, such as ngrok.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, code looks fine. But it is not externally accessible to other computers. If you are using different network to access the lab application then you need to forward your port in lab router. If you are using same network as lab application then check port status through these commands

```
nmap LAB_PC_IP

nc -vz LAB_PC_IP 5000

curl http://LAB_PC_IP:5000
```

Answer (score -2):

```
from waitress import serve

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # try this, will require pip install waitress
    serve(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8080) #WAITRESS

    # or this, replace this ip address w/ yours
    app.run(debug=True, host="10.1.10.170")
```